# ChainBridge: how to show transferred amount from ERC20 to Substrate parachain?

Tags: polkadot-js, chainbridge

after following the tutorial[https://chainbridge.chainsafe.io/local/] of running Chainbridge locally,

I can send 1 Substrate Native Token to ERC20

But when I sent 1, 100, 1000000, even 1000000000000000000 ERC20 tokens to 0xd4359..da27d, the ALICE Polkadot account balance does not increase after waiting 10 blocks...

```
accounts                    type      transactions  balances    
ALICE  5Grwva…GKutQY    type=sr25519       28      2.1529 MUnit
```

From this command: `subkey inspect //Alice`

```
  Network ID:        substrate 
 Secret seed:       0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a
  Public key (hex):  0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Account ID:        0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Public key (SS58): 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
  SS58 Address:      5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```

This confirms Alice 5Grwva is 0xd4359..da27d on Ethereum side

Logs from `cb-sol-cli erc20 ...` command sending tokens:

```
[erc20/deposit] Constructed deposit:
[erc20/deposit]   Resource Id: 0x000000000000000000000000000000c76ebe4a02bbc34786d860b355f5a5ce00
[erc20/deposit]   Amount: 0xd3c21bcecceda1000000
[erc20/deposit]   len(recipient): 32
[erc20/deposit]   Recipient: 0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
[erc20/deposit]   Raw: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3c21bcecceda10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
[erc20/deposit] Creating deposit to initiate transfer!
Waiting for tx: 0x43f50cebc459b1d959a515250be28a861639f8983ddc730ad8f464f9448cf58a...
```

Logs from running the ChainBridge:

```
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Starting ChainBridge... 
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Connecting to ethereum chain...          chain=eth url=ws://localhost:8545
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Connecting to substrate chain...         chain=sub url=ws://localhost:9944
2022/06/10 17:57:50 Connecting to ws://localhost:9944...
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Started eth chain                        system=core
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Started sub chain                        system=core
INFO[06-10|17:57:50] Polling Blocks...                        chain=eth block=14856
INFO[06-10|18:38:33] Got fungible transfer event!             chain=sub destination=0 resourceId=000000000000000000000000000000c76ebe4a02bbc34786d860b355f5a5ce00 amount=1000
INFO[06-10|18:38:33] Attempting to resolve message            chain=eth type=FungibleTransfer src=1 dst=0 nonce=1 rId=000000000000000000000000000000c76ebe4a02bbc34786d860b355f5a5ce00
INFO[06-10|18:38:33] Creating erc20 proposal                  chain=eth src=1 nonce=1
INFO[06-10|18:38:33] Watching for finalization event          chain=eth src=1 nonce=1
INFO[06-10|18:38:33] Submitted proposal vote                  chain=eth tx=0xbdc73d76fb45ed29b194afc6208785b37f38dd6851869fb95fab28673611f5bb src=1 depositNonce=1 gasPrice=20000000
INFO[06-10|18:38:48] Submitted proposal execution             chain=eth tx=0x366ce097f45b10e25d5047f366d08dc12d8b185e4c6deae49df1d58bea26cf97 src=1 dst=0 nonce=1 gasPrice=20000000
INFO[06-10|18:43:17] Handling fungible deposit event          chain=eth dest=1 nonce=7
INFO[06-10|18:43:17] Acknowledging proposal on chain          chain=sub nonce=7 source=0 resource=000000000000000000000000000000c76ebe4a02bbc34786d860b355f5a5ce00 method=Example.transfer
```

I think there is something missing in Polkadot JS Apps ->  definitions to the developer settings:
https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-Substrate-chain#polkadot-js-apps

```
{
  "chainbridge::ChainId": "u8",
  "ChainId": "u8",
  "ResourceId": "[u8; 32]",
  "DepositNonce": "u64",
  "ProposalVotes": {
    "votes_for": "Vec<AccountId>",
    "votes_against": "Vec<AccountId>",
    "status": "enum"
  },
  "Erc721Token": {
    "id": "TokenId",
    "metadata": "Vec<u8>"
  },
  "TokenId": "U256",
  "Address": "AccountId",
  "LookupSource": "AccountId"
}
```

I have to add `"AccountInfo": "AccountInfoWithDualRefCount"` on top of above settings to see the account balances.

And I can see ALICE transactions is increasing, but ALICE's balance has never increased after the transfer!

How can I show transferred amount from ERC20 to Substrate parachain?